# How can i set my text not to move but still have my css work properly

Tags: html, css

Ok so i have my tex in my div, and i set my div to move but i need my text to stay on the same place, can anyone help me with this?

```
<div id="nav_bar_menu">
      <div id="pocetna" ><div class="moving_background_nav_bar_img"><p id="pocetna_paragraf">POCETNA</p></div></div>

</div><!-- Menu -->
```

and here is my css

```
#nav_bar_menu {
    height: 38px;
    width: 580px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 93px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.moving_background_nav_bar_img {
    background: url(../Images/images/nav_bar_pictures_01.jpg);
    -moz-transition: top 0.7s;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.7s;
    -o-transition: top 0.7s;
    transition: top 0.7s;
    position: relative;
    height: 76px;
    top: 0;
    }
#pocetna {
    height: 38px;
    width: 131px;
    }
.moving_background_nav_bar_img:hover {
    top: -38px;
    position: relative;
    }
```

here is picture how it should look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw7ZN.png

if i set position fixed for text then if i scroll down it is still on its position on page... i dont want nav bar to follow me on scroll.

Comment: Float your text in a separate object on top of the other object.

Comment: But my hover will not work properly

Comment: Forget my last statement. I'll try and post a fiddle when I get to a computer, but don't move the object, move just the background using `background-position` with that, you'll need to make sure your object is tall enough to see the movement.

Comment: its ok ive made it work with some javascirpt :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do add the fixed positioning to the ID of the paragraph

```
#pocetna_paragraf{
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: But if i scroll the page down my paragraf i still moving with the page right ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok That's right the text wont move down when you scroll down. I'm sorry I released that later Anyway I tried different method but the problem when you hover over the text the ease effect will not work and when you hover over the image will work perfectly.

Hope someone will figure out what we need to do. Here is the code

CSS:

```
a#one {
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px; /* hide the text */
    background:url(background.png) top left;/* Do not forget to set your own image*/
}

a#one:hover {
    background-position:bottom left;
}

a#one {
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px; /* hide the text*/
    background:url(background.png) top left;
    -moz-transition:background 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:background 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#two{
position:absolute;
top:25px;
left:25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href ="http://google.com" id="one">Hover image</a>
<a href="http://google.com" id="two">Text</a>
```

Basically I made two links I hid the first one text with text-indent and made the background ease. This second one is just to show the link without scrolling up and down.

Comment: Thank you for trying ive done it with javascript :)


 $(document).ready(function() {
        
  $('#pocetna').animate({
   
   top: 0
  
  });
  
  $('#pocetna').hover(function() {
            $('.moving_background_nav_bar_img').animate({top: -38}, 0.1);
        }, function() {
   $('.moving_background_nav_bar_img').animate({top: 0}, 0.1);
  });

and done some set position to absolute and it works just fine :)